# could not find an overload for init that accepts supplied arguments

Tags: swift

```
        let r:Int = Int( CGFloat(y - (Int(_gridLowerLeftCorner.y) + _margin)) / CGFloat (_gridHeight) * (_numRows))
        let c:Int = Int( CGFloat(x - (Int(_gridLowerLeftCorner.x) + _margin)) / CGFloat (_gridWidth) * (_numCols))
```

I am getting could not find an overload for init that accepts supplied arguments does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

1) May be because of constant(let) change it to var

2) May be type mismatch between Int and CGFloat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have typed `Int` instead of `CGFloat`:

```
let r:Int = Int( CGFloat(y - (Int(_gridLowerLeftCorner.y) + _margin)) / CGFloat (_gridHeight) * (_numRows))

let c:Int = Int( CGFloat(x - (Int(_gridLowerLeftCorner.x) + _margin)) / CGFloat (_gridWidth) * (_numCols))
```

should be

```
let r:Int = Int( CGFloat(y - (CGFloat(_gridLowerLeftCorner.y) + _margin)) / CGFloat (_gridHeight) * (_numRows))

let c:Int = Int( CGFloat(x - (CGFloat(_gridLowerLeftCorner.x) + _margin)) / CGFloat (_gridWidth) * (_numCols))
```